Deploy Error "Feature Required: Field History Tracking This package requires field history tracking be enabled on this object: Contact"
For our first generation package, I receive a deploy error trying to upgrading a Production Environment:

Feature Required: Field History Tracking This package requires field
history tracking be enabled on this object: Contact. Ask the
subscriber to enable this feature, then retry the upgrade.

The strange thing is, from the package that is created, Field History Tracking is not enabled for SObject Contact. The previous package installment resulted in no errors and minor changes has been made for this new package.
Does anyone have an idea what can cause this error?

When you go to upload a new version in your packaging org, it gives you the option to specify any dependencies. Is it possible that the option was ticked in error? It could also be ticked automatically if any of your changes reference field history. For example, an Apex class might reference ContactHistory.


you are absolutely right, we added the usage of ContactHistory and that caused the issue.
I found it however strange, that deploying to our packagingOrg didn't result in deploy errors, and also, compiling all classes did not results in an error.
